# Why doesn't Facebook PHP SDK login work when I upload my php website to a free php hosting site?

Tags: facebook, authentication, hosting

Here is my code:

```
        //Facebook initialization

          $facebook = new Facebook(array(
              'appId'  => '345206108947993',
              'secret' => '50d371cf91e1b5a0462459ba17197453',
              'fileUpload' => true
          ));

          $user = $facebook->getUser();
          if ($user) {
              try {
                  // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
                  $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
              } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                  error_log($e);
                  $user = null;
              }
          }if ($user) {
              $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
          }


        //logout
        if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] === 'logout'){
          $facebook->destroySession();
          header('Location: index.php');
          die();
        }

        if($facebook->getUser()){
            echo '<img id="profpic" class="loggedin" src="https://graph.facebook.com/'. $user .'/picture?type=large" />
            <span id="name">User User</span>
            <span id="logout"><a href="index.php?action=logout" style="color:white">Logout</a></span>               
        }
        else{
            $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
            echo '<img id="profpic" class="loggedout" src="img/default_profile.jpg" />
            <table id="login" align="center">
                <tr><td align="center"><a href="' . $loginUrl . '"><img id="fb-login" src="img/facebook_login.png"></a></td></tr>
            </table>';
            echo $facebook->getUser();
        }
```

I've already tried this countless of times in localhost (using WAMPServer) and it works perfectly. but whenever I click "Login with Facebook using the uploaded website in 000webhost and eu5.org, it does not login. I already changed the corresponding site URl for the facebook app but it still does not work. It just redirects back to my site with the oAuth URL, but there is no session at all and $facebook->getUser() has a value of 0. Please help!

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: There's no error. It just redirects back to my page, but with the added facebook $_GET stuff in the url.